# Regular Expression: Using backreference in matched times {n}?

Tags: python, regex, backreference

I want to use regular expression to match a list of strings: `1a`, `2aa`, `3aaa` ... where the first digit in the string denotes how many a's are following that digit.

By instinct I think the back-reference might help, only that is not true.

In Regex we can use back-reference to match a previously captured sub-pattern.
For example, `(.+) \1` would match `aaa aaa`.

Can I use the back-reference in pattern matched times `{n}`, `{n,m}` or `{n,}`?

For example, `\da{\1}` ideally would match `3aaa`, however, I tested this with python building module `re`, it doesn't work. It seems the compiler understands `\da{\1}` as a different literal:

```
>>> re.compile('\da{\1}', re.DEBUG)
in
  category category_digit`
literal 97
literal 123
literal 1
literal 125
<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0xb7726790>

>>> re.compile('\da{1}', re.DEBUG)`
in
  category category_digit
max_repeat 1 1
  literal 97
<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0xb7707820>
```

Is this feature not implemented by the module or just because this feature cannot be supported by the basic regex algorithm?

Comment: I can't offhand find a place in the documentation that explains why this wouldn't be permitted, but I highly doubt that this would be supported. `{}` is expected digits, not a group result, which is what you're giving it--even though it does eventually return a number.

Comment: No, you can't. Regular expressions should parse regular languages

Comment: @JBernardo *Should*, being the key-word. Normally, when you want to find patterns that *start* and *end* with the same word, you would use something similar to `^([a-z]+)(.*)\1$`, which is essentially what the OP is trying to accomplish, but inside `{}` instead.

Comment: @newfurniturey No, it is not. The number of repetitions cannot be chosen arbitrarily by the language itself

Comment: @JBernardo Doesn't a back reference literally repeat the matched expression in place of the back reference? How is it different from substitution?

Comment: @newfurniturey yes, arguably the number of repetition is arbitrary at the moment a pattern like `\da{\1}` is defined, but so is the pattern in `(.+) \1`. So how does it affect the algorithm implementation? I think `\da{\1}` is exactly the same as `(.+) \1` from the implementation perspective.

Comment: Also, try `re.compile('\da{\1}', re.DEBUG)` and see what you get. It interprets the `{` and `}` as literals (as if prepended with a backslash), not as special. Compare to `re.compile('\da{1}', re.DEBUG)`.

Comment: @Evert Thanks for the remind, it is confirmed. So this kind of back-reference is not supported by the language itself as it is understand as a different literal by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting idea, but I think the "{n}" is processed when the regular expression is compiled.

You can do something like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = '3aaa'
>>> m = re.search('(\d+)a', text)
>>> pat = '\d+a{%s}' % m.group(1)
>>> n = re.search(pat, text)
>>> n.group(0)
'3aaa'
```

If you want to exclude patterns like '3aaaaa', you should need a '\b' at the end the pattern (which Python makes you enter as '\b'):

```
pat = '\d+a{%s}\\b' % m.group(1)
```